# PHP secure URL variables

Tags: php, url

I'm having troubles to secure my URL.

I've got that one :

`http://localhost/Projet_4/P4_Code/index.php?action=listCommentMember&id=15`

If someone want to change the `"15"` to something else, he can do it easily. And I'm trying to avoid that.
I tried to secure the `id` by putting an `isset` like follows:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']){
        myFunction
} else {
    echo 'wrong id'; 
}
```

But it doesn't works.

Comment: Why you don't store the id in  a session variable ?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['id']){` < that should be throwing you a parse error with the missing bracket.

Comment: your train of thought is wrong. Urls will always be editable, your backend should decide whether someone can access the resource or not.

Comment: So you want `if($_GET['id'] == 15){ echo "ok"; }else{ echo "nok"; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `(int)` before `$_GET['id']`.

This move will transform any string into number and will not affect on number as it.

```
$s1 = 'fsdfsdf';
$s2 = '43';
$s2 = '';
echo (int)$s1;
echo (int)$s2;
echo (int)$s3;
```

Outputs:

```
0
43
0
```

Also, you can add `is_numeric($_GET['id'])` in your `if` statement.

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
   // your stuff
} else {
   echo 'nope';
}
```

Comment: What if the user change 15 to 9 for example ?

Comment: @executable, then it should be checked on the valid value.

Comment: He want to "secure" the id

Comment: @executable, only his DB knows which `id` is valid. Securing of integer value enough with this steps.

Comment: ... and if it has to come from the DB, then casting the value to an int at this stage is pointless - as you *are* going to be using a prepared statement with bound parameters of course.

Comment: @CD001, yes, I will use, but the OP...who knows)